# Gauss-Krueger coordinates in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

I want to show the coordinates of my map in gauss-krüger coordinates, but nothing works. I tried another projection, displayProjection, lonLat.transform but the answers are the same. 
my source projection is EPSG:900913

Comment: you need to know the epsg code of gauss-kruger system.